# Search for a piece of string Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, coldfusion, sublimetext2

How would I search for all ColdFusion cflocation tags without the attribute of addtoken? Using Sublime Text 2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding text in source code, not programming.

Comment: @Dan It is about finding this occurrence in my ColdFusion code so I can program to add the attribute of addtoken="false" because it is true by default and it shows the session token in the URL string. Finding how to do that is important for keeping the  code safe and clean. If that is not a programming question what is?

Comment: Seesm to fit this: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Straight from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Following those guidelines, one can ask questions about WordPad or Notepad since you can write code using either of them.

Comment: @ScottStroz. Yup. And fortunately there are humans at the other end of the guidelines to sort out when people have got the wrong end of the stick regarding asking questions, or marking them for closure.

Answer (score 1):

This can be used to find all occurrences of the cflocation tag without the addtoken attribute.
Pasted this expression into the tool File Locator Lite.
    `<cflocation\s+url="[^"]*"\s*>`

Comment: That's pretty good, but I'd suggest a modification to account for either quote type, or lack of, and for spaces surrounding the ='s. `<cflocation\s+url\s*=\s*("|')?([^>]*)("|')?\s*>`. Because the quote type might differ or be non-existent, I changed the `[^"]` to `[^>]`

Answer (score 1):

One should use a negative lookahead for this. Peter Boughton will - no doubt - finetune this for me, but I only have a coupla min spare to come up with it. This should work:

```
<cflocation(?![^>]+addtoken)[^>]+>
```

I've not tested it in ST, but it's a fairly generic pattern, so should work. Lemme know if not, and I'll finetune further.